# Uar paginate() junto a unique()

Tags: laravel

Quiero mostrar todos los registros de una `tabla pivote` en una consulta, pero hay un campo llamado `code` que se repite ya que es común para un miso registro, y para listarlos no deseo mostrar los registro que tienen el mismo código, sólo uno ya que se trata de la misma operación.

Con este código lo logro, pero no sé como incluir el paginate():

```
$badges = Badge::all()->unique('code');
return view('badges.index', compact('badges'));
```

Otra manera podría ser con `groupBy` pero tampoco lo he logrado.

Comment: groupBy debería funcionar, sólo debes especificar qué campos quieres que estén agrupados, ya que algunas columnas son *non-aggregated columns*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba esto

```
$badges = Badge::select('code')->groupBy('code')->paginate(15);
```